# Split a pattern string into columns in select query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a `person` table with below structure.

```
CREATE TABLE person(id integer, details LONGTEXT);
INSERT INTO person(id,details) 
VALUES
(1, "name:Tahir,age:30,sex:male"),
(2, "name:Tina,sex:female,status:1");
```

**Problem:** *I have some limitations on db end, can't add new tables/columns so have to improvise with available column that is LONGTEXT details. So, I have no other way but find a workaround.*

So, I want to split details column by comma and show results in difference columns. Like, in this example result would be id, name,age, sex, status

I believe that is possible with aggregate functions and I tried to produce a query like below

```
SELECT id,
if(person.details like '%name:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'name:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `name`,
if(person.details like '%age:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'age:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `age`,
if(person.details like '%sex:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'sex:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `sex`,
if(person.details like '%status:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'status:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `status`
FROM person
```

above query fetches data correctly for age but name and sex gets 0. Could you please figure out what I am missing here?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqyqb7Vhvs7kKYifFywmkV/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting apparent strings as unsigned (integers).  No need to cast:

```
SELECT
  id,
  if(person.details like '%name:%',substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'name:',-1),',',1),null) as `name`,
  if(person.details like '%age:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'age:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `age`,
  if(person.details like '%sex:%',substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'sex:',-1),',',1),null) as `sex`
FROM person
```